# Interesting examples of non-locally compact topological groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, harmonic-analysis

Harmonic analysis is concentrated mostly on studying [locally compact groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_group). I would like to ask people about examples of **non-locally compact topological groups** that are interesting in connection with some applications in mathematics (or physics). I must confess that I know only two examples:

- topological vector spaces are studied as examples of topological groups (with the additive group operation) to which [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Pontryagin_duality_for_topological_vector_spaces) is sometimes transferred from the class of locally compact abelian groups,
- the [groups of diffeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Diffeomorphism_group) of smooth manifolds are studied in the theory of infinite dimensional manifolds.

Can people enlighten me about other similar subjects? (If possible, with motivations.)

Comment: Sergei, i think it might be a good idea (for the visibility of the question) to add the mathematical physics tag here.

Comment: Konstantinos, thank you, I did it!

Comment: Although harmonic analysis starts with locally compact groups, it also deals with representations in mostly non-locally compact groups --- unitary groups of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I don't think that harmonic analysis studies locally compact groups, but rather that locally compact groups is a natural setting for harmonic analysis. Also many people study locally compact groups and are not involved in harmonic analysis.

Comment: A huge well-studied class of topological groups is Banach spaces. Since continuous group homomorphisms between Banach spaces are bounded operators, it can really be considered as a subclass. Another (not disjoint) class is that of automorphism group of relational structures, that is, closed subgroups of symmetric groups. The very first example is the group of permutations of an infinite countable set (whose Polish group topology was introduced by L. Onofri in 1927).

Comment: @YCor : "I don't think that harmonic analysis studies locally compact groups, but rather that locally compact groups is a natural setting for harmonic analysis." I hardly feel the difference, but I don't insist, we can edit the formulation.

Comment: See [$\pi$-base](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=Groupable%20%26%20~Locally%20Compact)

Comment: How about $\mathbb{Q}$? How about $\mathbb{Z}^\omega$ (= Baire space), or similar infinite products of non-compact groups?

Comment: @NateEldredge which topology on $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Presumably the standard one, induced by inclusion in $\mathbb R$

Comment: $\mathbb C_p$, the completion of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$, is an important example of topological field which is not locally compact.

Comment: There are plenty of group topologies on $\mathbf{Q}$. It may be useful to assume some kind of completeness to avoid such endless lists of examples. Polish groups is already a large well-studied class and includes many of the groups mentioned here, such as $S_\infty$, $U(\ell^2)$, separable Banach spaces, $\mathbf{Z}^\omega$ and more generally countable products of countable groups, as well as their closed subgroups, such as the projective limit of free groups $F_n$. Also $\mathbf{C}_p$ is a non-locally compact Polish field, and so is $k((t))$ when $k$ is an infinite countable discrete field.

Answer (score 11):

- [Infinite-dimensional Lie groups](//ams.org/msc/msc2010.html?s=22E65); e.g. [locally convex groups](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2261066), [pro-Lie groups](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2337107), [ind-groups](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1925340).
- Central extensions thereof; e.g. [Virasoro group](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2362888).
- [Loop groups](//ams.org/msc/msc2010.html?s=22E67), [Current groups](//ams.org/msc/msc2010.html?s=81R10).
- Central extensions thereof, [Kac-Moody groups](//ams.org/msc/msc2010.html?s=20G44).

Comment: Francois, could you, please, say a few words on where this is used?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov As with all groups, one studies their homogeneous symplectic manifolds, resp. (projective) unitary representations as potential models of classical, resp. quantum systems. Pressley-Segal ([1986](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=900587), introduction) cite some such successes, but beyond that I see mainly hope and *l’art pour l’art* fun...

Answer (score 8):

A couple of common classes of examples you may have overlooked:

- The rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ with their usual topology.  More generally, any non-closed subgroup of a locally compact Hausdorff group will be a non-locally compact group (in its subspace topology).  There are lots of situations where it's convenient to prove something about a locally compact group by working on a dense subgroup.
- Infinite products of non-compact groups with their product topology.  Some of these are topological vector spaces like $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, but for instance, $\mathbb{Z}^\omega$ is another simple example (it's homeomorphic to Baire space, and to the set of irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$).  Products arise naturally any time you want to say "give me a whole sequence of these".  The failure of such groups to have a Haar measure is a frequent sticking point in analysis and probability.

Comment: Nate, to tell the truth, I don't understand how can separating $\mathbb Q$ from $\mathbb R$ be useful if the topology is preserved.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov, perhaps you might ask a number theorist …?

Answer (score 7):

There are two quite popular areas related to "big" or "large" groups. One concerns extreme amenability and fixed point properties (see [Pestov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512564.pdf)), and the other concerns harmonic analysis and the representation theory (see [Borodin - Olshanski](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0409333.pdf)).

Comment: R W as far as I can see, they change the definition of topological group. In their considerations the operation of multiplication should not be jointly continuous, but separately continuous, is it?

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov - Where do you see this?

Comment: In the paper by Vladimir Pestov: the multiplication in $U(\ell^2)$ is separately continuous with respect to the pointwise convergence, not jointly.

Comment: @Sergei Akhbarov The multiplication in the unitary group is jointly continuous in the operator topology.

Comment: Ah, yes! Because $||A||=1$ for all $A\in U(\ell^2)$ (you mean in the strong operator topology). Excuse me, I confused this with the group of all invertibe elements.

Comment: @Sergei Akhbarov Weak or strong operator topology, either way. It's the same topology on $U(\ell^2)$.

Comment: @user95282 yes, ok! You said they study representations of $U(\ell^2)$?

Comment: @Sergei Akhbarov Not so much representations of $U(\ell^2)$, but group representations in $U(\ell^2)$. See G.W. Mackey, Bull AMS 3,1 (1980) 543-698.

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: See my comment to Peter Michor's answer.

Comment: @AndréHenriques thank you, I already printed this article, it's useful!

Answer (score 6):

Quantum mechanics: The unitary group $U$ of a Hilbert space. If you use the norm topology, then it is a Banach Lie group with bounded skew hermitian operators as Lie algebra. But unbounded self-adjoint operators $A$ (Schrödinger operators) lead to 1-parameter semigroups $e^{itA}$ in $U$, where now the strong operator topology plays a role.

Comment: Some relevant facts about $U(H)$ in its strong operator topology (SOT) can be found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5891. In particular it is a topological group (as explained in the linked paper, a number of prominent references explicitly state that $(U(H),$SOT$)$ is not a topological group!). More precisely, it is a Polish group. Even more, when restricted to $U(H)\subset B(H)$, the strong operator topology, the weak operator topology, the ultra-strong topology, the ultra-weak topology, and the compact open topology all agree.

Answer (score 3):

This is far from the use of topological groups in analysis, but:

In homotopy theory a basic background fact that is that a (based connected) space is always the classifying space of a topological group. In a little more detail: the following four categories (with suitable notions of weak homotopy equivalence) are equivalent for purposes of homotopy theory.

1. Based path-connected spaces
2. Based connected simplicial sets
3. Simplicial groups
4. Topological groups

So in some sense arbitrary topology groups play a role in homotopy theory.

In practice homotopy-theorists work with 2 as a substitute for 1, and with 3 as a tool for 2, but 4 is part of the picture. Roughly speaking, the topological group associated with a based space $X$ is the space of based loops in $X$, but in order to represent this homotopy type by an actual topological group one ordinarily goes through simplicial groups.

Answer (score 3):

The question mentions topological vector spaces, but aren't Banach spaces a special case of sufficient interest to merit explicit mention? Every infinite dimensional Banach space is a non-locally compact topological group under addition and the norm topology.